# Как доставать из строки текст определенного образца?

Tags: php

Можно ли доставать из строки текст определенного образца? Допустим, мне надо достать дату из текст в формате дд.мм, но я не знаю какие там числа будут, поэтому сравнивать не с чем. И мне нужно достать эту дату зная только что там будет такой формат записи(дд.мм) и состоять он будет из цифр.

Comment: Регулярными выражениями можно, покажите пример строки и что надо вытянуть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По такому принципу

```
$search = 'И мне нужно достать эту дату зная только что там будет такой     формат записи(06.05) и состоять он будет из цифр.';

preg_match_all('~\d{2}\.\d{2}~', $search, $all);

echo '<pre>'; var_dump($all); echo '</pre>';
```